# Recommendation textbooks on D-module

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, textbook-recommendation, d-modules

I am going to take part in a seminar on D-modules and applications, the textbooks that will be used are :  [D-modules, Perverse Sheaves, and Representation Theory](http://www.springer.com/birkhauser/mathematics/book/978-0-8176-4363-8), [A Primer of Algebraic D-Modules](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521559081)

However, I am a beginner in this theory and I found hard to understand the main road in these books.

Could you please suggest me some other textbooks that are easier or more intuitive?

Thanks.

Comment: I recommend giving Coutinho's book another chance. I am not aware of an "easier" introductory textbook.

Comment: also asked at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/174975/recommendation-textbooks-on-d-module

Comment: Aside from the duplication with stackexchange, this type of question needs to be community-wiki (if it's not closed first).   There is an out-of-print Academic Press book by A. Borel, *Algebraic D-Modules*, which won't be any easier for a beginner than the listed Birkhauser book.  There are no other "textbooks" out there, but I agree with Konstantin's recommendation.  It's also important to approach the subject with some strong motivation from earlier study.

Comment: I'd also endorse the Coutinho book. It is much more readable than the Borel collection. Thinking of Bernstein's application about meromorphic continuation of complex powers of absolute values of polynomials is already a very striking application, mentioned in Coutinho. Also looking toward the Beilinson-Bernstein reformulation/"reproof" of Casselman's subrepresentation theorem.

Also, I think Milicic has some D-modules notes on-line at his Utah web-page, whose URL everyone else can ascertain as quickly as I. :)

But, yes, as consolation, it's non-trivial to see the motivation.

Comment: I have finished the Coutinho's book, and I changed my attitude for this book, too. 

Thank you very much for your recommendations.